# Dropped server connection

Tags: ios, alamofire

I am using Alamofire for my app network communications.

Sometimes the connection to the server gets dropped randomly and Charles would say "Remote server closed the connection before sending response header."

The disconnection doesn't get caught by Alamofire if it happens unless I am doing it wrong.

Is there a way I can monitor the server disconnection using Alamofire automatically?

```
request(.POST, url, parameters: params)
            .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
            .validate(contentType: ["application/json"])
            .responseJSON { (request, response, json, errorResponse) in

                if errorResponse == nil {
                    if let object = json as? NSDictionary {
                        funcParam(info: object)
                    }
                }else{
                    error(apiError: errorResponse)
                    println("loginUser: error -> \(errorResponse?.localizedDescription)")
                }
        }
```